# (JQuery) 'table.class' doesn't work and i can't figure out why. It selects tables with other classes too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is pretty much self-explanatory. Please take a look:

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- importing the latest jquery (1.6.4) here -->    

<table class="notThisOne" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 20px;">
<colgroup>
<col>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="not">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<b>Nicholas O'Reilly</b>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>nikoreilly@hotmail.com </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="not">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<b>John Smith</b>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>jsmithjr@gmail.com </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>



<table class="contactListRow" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 20px;">
<colgroup>
<col>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="contactListRow">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<b>Nicholas O'Reilly</b>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>nikoreilly@hotmail.com </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="contactListRow">
<td>
</td>
<td>
<b>John Smith</b>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>jsmithjr@gmail.com </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">



$('table.contactListRow').each(function(i) {

    $name = "";
    $email = "";

    $('td').each(function(ii) {
        $col = ii%5;

        if( $col == 1){
            $name = $(this).text();
        }

        if( $col == 3){
            $email = $(this).text();
        }

        if( $col == 4){
            //$(this).html('<a href="javascript: openwindow(\'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=&quot;'+$name+'&quot; &lt;'+$email+'&gt;\')">Email</a>');
            $(this).text(i+"_"+ii);
        }

    });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that any table gets altered, even if the class is not the one specified.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I only need it running on Firefox 6+ (its for personal use only).

Comment: I assume you have included jquery and document ready?

Comment: Yes, the scripts runs when the document is ready. @mu is too short: Didn't know about the prefix. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
$('td').each(function(ii) {
```

to

```
$(this).find('td').each(function(ii) {
```

Comment: I had to select only one, but all answers are perfect. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
$('td').each(function(ii) {
```

Your `$('td')` selects **all** table cells whether they're in the table you want or not. So you're not quite altering every table so much as you are (accidentally) altering every table cell.

Try using `$(this).find('td')` instead, that will limit your table cell selector to those that are within the tables that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('td').each(function(ii)
```

won't this change *every* td element?

Maybe something more like

```
xxxxx
```

Nevermind, I'm not yet doing much jScript, my solution is probably not right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are selecting *all* `<td>` elements with this line:

```
$('td').each(function(ii) {
```

Instead of that you can use `find` to look within the table that was already selected, something like this:

```
$(this).find('td').each(function(ii) {
```

(Or, to select all `<td>` elements that belong to a table of the specified class you could say `$('table.contactListRow td').each(function(ii) {`.)